# Python Code working fine in Google Colab but not when deployed in Google Function

Tags: python, python-requests, google-cloud-functions, google-colaboratory, tweepy

I have some Python code that works fine in Colab but when I transfer the code into a Google Function it fails.

I am pulling an image from Google Drive with requests and then posting to Twitter via API so I think I need to dump the image into a temporary folder within functions. Not sure why this isn't needed on Colab? Seeing that they are both cloud applications!

I am a Python beginner self taught via online tutorials and this website :) but i cannot find the Python code which enables me to fix this issue anywhere online.

If anyone can help I would be grateful been trying for two weeks now to fix this issue.

Colab code example below the full code is much larger but this is the only part that is broken:

```py
# file link is a URL of a Google Drive image
r = requests.get(file_download_link)

# open image from r.content
open('image', "wb").write(r.content)

# combine this with some text and then upload via api to Twitter
api.update_with_media('image', tweet_summary)
```

Code works fine in Colab.

Error message in Google Function is:

> tweet-ET-evening-messageyl620abrfpo2 Exception on / [POST] Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/functions_framework/**init**.py", line 99, in view_func return function(request._get_current_object()) File "/workspace/main.py", line 39, in tweet_evening_message open('image', "wb").write(r.content) OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'image'

Answer (score 0):

With the `open('image', "wb")` you are writing to the local file system but Google Function does not have any local file system.

Hard to see how the `api` works but most libraries accept either a file or a stream when uploading. So the goal is to keep the picture content in memory and pass it further.

Comment: Odd how this code works on Colab though given they are both cloud based applications? 

The Twitter api needs to have the image pre downloaded before the upload so it needs to be downloaded somewhere. Probably the temporary folder within Google Function would work. I just don’t know the code!

Comment: Cloud is not equal to cloud. Colab is a workspace where you get some storage. Functions are minimal and should not have any side effects (like writing a file). Which package are you using?

Comment: Do you know the Google Functions python code to write this file to a temp folder where i believe i can use memory to store the file temporarily.

Comment: Not out of the box, you coukd use the blob storage service and delete afterwards, but it has a bad code smell. If you tell me which twitter package you are using I ll look for a way to avoid writing to the file system.

Comment: Using Tweepy does that help?

Comment: Yes, if you check the [API description](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.10.0/api.html#API.update_with_media) (btw, you are not using the current version), you see that there is parameter `file` which is a file object.

Without trying to recreate your code locally, I guess that  

`api.update_with_media('image', tweet_summary, file=r.content)`

should do the trick. When reading the API descriptin I think that a file ending in the file name will be helpful.